# C++ - Return by value behavior

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn how copies work when a function returns by value. I'm confused by the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class X {
    public:
        virtual ~X() { cout << "~X() " ; }
        X() { cout << "X() "; }
        X(X const& other) {
            cout << "X(X const&) ";
        }
};

X f(X x) {
    cout << "# ";
    return x;
}

X g(X x) {
    X y = x;
    cout << "# ";
    return y;
}

int main() {
    X a;
    cout << endl << "f: ";
    a = f(a);
    cout << endl << "g: ";
    a = g(a);
    cout << endl;       
}
```

The output is:

```
X()
f: X(X const&) # X(X const&) ~X() ~X()
g: X(X const&) X(X const&) # ~X() ~X()
~X()
```

This suggests, that `f` does a copy of `x` before returning, but `g` doesn't. How is this possible, does `x` not act as a normal variable in the scope of `f` because it is one of its arguments? What is the general rule for this type of behavior?

Comment: "copy-elision" (or rather "NRVO") at work here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What constructor or operator is used in a return (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889861/what-constructor-or-operator-is-used-in-a-return-c)

Comment: Whether or not you build with compiler optimizations enabled *may* change the result here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the optimization that I believe is taking place for `g()` but not for `f()`.

> **Non-mandatory** elision of copy/move (since C++11) operations:
>
> In a return statement, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile object with automatic storage duration, **which isn't a function parameter** or a catch clause parameter, and which is of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type. This variant of copy elision is known as NRVO, "named return value optimization".

(excerpt from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). The bold text is done by me to mark important parts regarding the question)

It's non-mandatory, so might change with compiler/optimizations included.